# Reading from a temporary directory in python: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TemporaryDirectory

Tags: python, windows, filepath, temporary-files

I have created a temporary directory in python where I am saving a bunch of .png files for later use. My code seemingly works fine up until the point where I need to access those .png files - when I do so, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TemporaryDirectory
```

The error is thrown when I pass the temporary directory in os.path.join:

```
import os
import tempfile

t_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
os.path.join (t_dir, 'sample.png')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-32-47ee4fce12c7>", line 1, in <module>
    os.path.join (t_dir, 'sample.png')

  File "C:\Users\donna\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 75, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)

  TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TemporaryDirectory
```

However, using gettempdir() seems to work fine.

```
import os
import tempfile
t_dir = tempfile.gettempdir()
os.path.join (t_dir, 'sample.png')
```

The python docs suggests tempfile.TemporaryDirectory works using the same rules as tempfile.mkdtemp() (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory), and I would think tempfile.TemporaryDirectory is the preferred method for python 3.x. Any ideas why this throws an error or if one of these methods is preferred over the other for this use case?

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure why the error occurs, but one way to get around it is to call `.name` on the `TemporaryDirectory`:

```
>>> t_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
>>> os.path.join(t_dir.name, 'sample.png')
'/tmp/tmp8y5p62qi/sample.png'
>>>
```

You can then run `t_dir.cleanup()` to remove the `TemporaryDirectory` later.

<strike>FWIW, I think `.name` should be mentioned in the [TemporaryDirectory docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory), I discovered this by running `dir(t_dir)`.</strike> (Edit: it's mentioned now)

You should consider placing it in a `with` statement, e.g. adapted from the one in the official docs linked above:

```
# create a temporary directory using the context manager
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as t_dir:
    print('created temporary directory', t_dir)
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory says:

> The directory name can be retrieved from the name attribute of the returned object. When the returned object is used as a context manager, the name will be assigned to the target of the as clause in the with statement, if there is one.

So, either you do without the context manager, and use `t_dir.name`

```
t_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
os.path.join (t_dir.name, 'sample.png')
```

or, using a context manager, you can do:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as t_dir:
   os.path.join (t_dir, 'sample.png')
```